# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' in formula

Tags: compile-error

I keep getting 'Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
if(Owner.Trip_A_1_Week__c=TRUE,TRUE,
IF(Owner.Trip_A_2_Weeks__c =TRUE,TRUE,
IF(Owner.Trip_A_3_Days__c=TRUE,TRUE,
IF(Owner.Trip_B_1_Week__c=TRUE,TRUE,
IF(Owner.Trip_B_2_Weeks__c =TRUE,TRUE,
IF(Owner.Trip_B_3_Days__c=TRUE,TRUE) 
),
AND, if(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_1__c=TRUE, TRUE,
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_2__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_3__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_4__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_5__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_6__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_7__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_8__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_9__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_10__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_11__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_A_Zone_12__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_1__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_2__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_3__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_4__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_5__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_6__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_7__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_8__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_9__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_10__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_11__c=TRUE,TRUE, 
IF(Owner.Trip_B_Zone_12__c=TRUE,TRUE)
))
```

Comment: Hi JLSI - can you explain what you're trying to do with this code? I think you're missing more than one parenthesis, and also you have commas where there shouldn't be commas -- but I also think this could be drastically simplified. If you explain what the logic is supposed to do we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your reply! I am trying to have a custom checkbox = true if...
Trip A Week 2 OR Week 1 OR 3 Days OR Trip B Week 2 OR Week 1 OR 3 Days is True AND IF Trip A Zone 1 Or 2 OR 3...(and so on all the way to 12) OR Trip B Zone 1 OR 2 or 3 (all the way to 12) is True.

Comment: That's what I thought - see sfdcfox's answer below about how you don't need all the IF statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic can be expressed without a single "true" at all; Boolean values are already Boolean values, so you don't need to compare them to Boolean values. In other words:

```
IF(SomeCheckbox__c=TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Is the same as:

```
SomeCheckbox__c
```

Applying this knowledge, your formula becomes far simpler:

```
AND(
    OR(
        Owner.Trip_A_1_Week__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_2_Weeks__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_3_Days__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_1_Week__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_2_Weeks__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_3_Days__c
    ),
    OR(
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_1__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_2__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_3__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_4__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_5__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_6__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_7__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_8__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_9__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_10__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_11__c,
        Owner.Trip_A_Zone_12__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_1__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_2__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_3__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_4__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_5__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_6__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_7__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_8__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_9__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_10__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_11__c,
        Owner.Trip_B_Zone_12__c
    )
)
```

You may need to adjust this if you've made a mistake somewhere about your AND/OR logic, however.

Comment: That worked - thank you!!

Comment: The errors went away, however, it is simply checking all the accounts - not just the ones with the Trip A, Zone 1, 2, etc checked. Is this what you were referring to may happen due to the changes with the AND/OR logic?

Comment: @JLSI Yes, you'll maybe want to review your thoughts on how AND/OR works, and maybe write a "truth table" to help you work through the problem.